# how to access listview of other form

Tags: c#

I am developing a mp3 player with face detection. I have two forms.

In first form there is media player and face detection code and in second form code for creating playlist.

I want that when i click on create button the name of playlist should be display in listbox of  first form.

This is some of my code for form1

```
 private Capture cap;
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cap = new Capture(0);
        _dataBasePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\db1.mdb";


        // adjust path to find your xml

        haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
        mouth = new HaarCascade("Mouth.xml");

        lefteye = new HaarCascade("eye_left.xml");
        righteye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml");
    }

    public void DataBasePath(string path)
    {
        _dataBasePath = path;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame())
        {
            if (nextFrame != null)
            {
                // there's only one channel (greyscale), hence the zero index
                //var faces = nextFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haar)[0];
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                Image<Gray, Byte> gray = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                Image<Gray, Byte> gray1 = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                Image<Gray, Byte> gray2 = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                var faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(
                         haar, 1.4, 4,
                         HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                         new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8)
                         )[0];
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in faces)
                {
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    nextFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                    facesnap = f.rect;


                    int halfheight = facesnap.Height/2;
                    int start = facesnap.X;
                    int start1 = facesnap.Y;

                    Rectangle top = new Rectangle(start,start1,facesnap.Width,halfheight);
                    int start2 = top.Bottom;

                    Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(start, start2, facesnap.Width, halfheight);


                    //Set the region of interest on the faces
                    gray.ROI = bottom;
                    MCvAvgComp[][] mouthsDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(mouth,
                                                    1.1, 10,
                                                  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                                    new Size(40,30));
                    gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;


                    foreach (MCvAvgComp m in mouthsDetected[0])
                    {
                        Rectangle mouthRect = m.rect;
                        mouthRect.Offset(bottom.X, bottom.Y);
                        nextFrame.Draw(mouthRect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                        Rectangle mouthphoto = new Rectangle(mouthRect.X - 5, mouthRect.Y - 10, mouthRect.Width + 5, mouthRect.Height +10);
                        detectedmouth = mouthphoto;
                    }
                    int halfwidth =facesnap.Width/2;

                    Rectangle toprighteye =new Rectangle(start,start1,halfwidth,halfheight);
                    int leftx = toprighteye.Right;
                    Rectangle toplefteye = new Rectangle(leftx, start1, halfwidth, halfheight);

                    gray1.ROI =toplefteye;

                    MCvAvgComp[][] detectedlefteye = gray1.DetectHaarCascade(lefteye, 1.1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(30,10));
                    gray1.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                    foreach (MCvAvgComp eyesnapleft in detectedlefteye[0])
                    {
                        Rectangle eyeRectleft = eyesnapleft.rect;
                        eyeRectleft.Offset(toplefteye.X, toplefteye.Y);
                        nextFrame.Draw(eyeRectleft, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);

                        lefteyesnap = eyeRectleft;


                    }

                    gray2.ROI = toprighteye;

                    MCvAvgComp[][] detectedrighteye = gray2.DetectHaarCascade(righteye, 1.1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(30, 10));
                    gray2.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                    foreach (MCvAvgComp eyesnapright in detectedrighteye[0])
                    {
                        Rectangle eyeRectright = eyesnapright.rect;
                        eyeRectright.Offset(toprighteye.X, toprighteye.Y);
                        nextFrame.Draw(eyeRectright, new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 2);

                        righteyesnap = eyeRectright;


                    }




                }


                pictureBox1.Image = nextFrame.ToBitmap();
            }
        }

    }
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataBasePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\db1.mdb";


        // adjust path to find your xml

        haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
        mouth = new HaarCascade("Mouth.xml");

        lefteye = new HaarCascade("eye_left.xml");
        righteye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml");
    }
```

this is some of the code for form2

```
namespace Face_Detection_Concept
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    #region Global Variables

    public const string Separator = ",";

    public static ArrayList searchAudio = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList searchVideo = new ArrayList();



    public static StreamWriter sw;
    public string fnm;
    #endregion

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set default values
        cmbType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        chkIncSubDir.Checked = true;

        LoadFormats();


        txtFilename.Text = "PlayList1.wpl";
    }
```

when i m use this code for accessing listbox of form1 on button click event

```
new Form1().playlistviewbar.items.add(playlistname);
```

but this is not displaying the name of the playlist.is there any solution?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms this is maybe an answer to your question.

Comment: Is your second form a child of your first or are they seperate?

Comment: Can you show how both forms gets created, I feel like we have some misunderstanding

Comment: simple i have created form1 that i have shown in question and a seperate form 2 but i have shown form2 in a button click of form1. the code of form2 is too big so i am giving some portion of it in ques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the modifiers property of the ListBox to public and you can access it in the known way.

Deliver the reference of the calling Form to the called Form and take it to access the LB.

```
// Call:
Form2 test = new Form2(this);

//Constructor Form2:
public Form2 (Form1 FormToAccess)

//Access:
FormToAccess.listBox1.... = ... ;
```

Comment: He's accessing the child from the parent, not the parent from the child, so this doesn't need to be done at all.  In addition, this entire practice should be discouraged; it is poor design for a child form to have any direct knowledge of the parent, or for the parent to expose it's controls (i.e. the listbox) publicly.

Comment: but in the form1 on a button click event i hve put this code to show the form2 
        private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         new Form2().Show();
        }
so if i use this code it shows error like facedetection.Form2 does not contain constructor that thakes 0 arguments

Comment: i got it you are right.. i was using `new form2().show();` so that i was getting error but now using `form2 test=new form2(this);` it actually works.. thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* expose the control directly by making in `public`, a better approach would be to create methods that manipulate the `ListBox` contents.  that gives you the flexibility to change out the control without breaking the calling form:

```
public void AddPlayList(string playlistname)
{
    this.playlistviewbar.Items.Add(playlistname);
}
public string[] GetPlayLists()
{
    return this.playlistviewbar.Items;  // converting to strings if necessary.
}
```

Comment: While this change would be a good idea, currently he has the problem that he's trying to access the listbox before it's initialized, since it's created when the form is loaded, not in it's constructor.  Your answer doesn't' address that.

Comment: sorry but can you explain in this code of what's referance **this** will get?
so that i can easily understand i able to implement it

Comment: and i want to call this in button click event of other form.. so if i define it in form1 so how can i call it in form2.

Comment: You have to pass a reference to `form1` somehow (typically in the constructor if it's a required reference or a property if it's not.  Then just call it like any other method - `form1.AddPlayList("blah");`

Comment: i tried but in this it shows the error that object referance is required for the non-static field,method or property.

Comment: How are you passing a `Form1` reference to the other form?  My guess is you're trying to call is statically (`Form1.AddPlayList()`) rather than using a reference to the existing form.  The reference could be passed either in the constructor or through a property of the second form.

Comment: you mean i should have use like this?
`form1 fobj1;

 public Form2(form1 fobj)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

fobj1=fobj

        }`

and then `fobj.AddPlaylist();`

Comment: That would work.  Not crazy about the variable names, but structurally that's the idea.

Comment: but the prob is that i have also inversely use form2 in form1 means i have put this code for showing form2 in form1 button click event
`new form2().show();`
so that if i use above way then it give errer at this line that form() constructor have 0 arguments

Comment: ok i got it using the above way in form2 and for showing form2 in buttonclick of form one i have use like this and it works!!
**Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();**

Answer (score 0):

your `Capture` object `cap` is null, you should initialize it before starting the timer, for example:

```
public void form_load()
    {

        cap = new Capture();

        //Init and start Timer

    }
```

Comment: but in the form_load event i have initialized it

Comment: And when do you start your timer? I am giving you an example as you did not provide the initialization routine for the timer and Capture objects

Comment: In the  InitializeComponent() method i have initialize the timer..   okk  i have do this and delete **cap=new capture();** from the form_load event and it doesn't gives the error. but now also it dont shoe the playlist name in the list box. is there any solution?

Comment: How is it working if you deleted the initialization call??? can you post your `form_load` implementation?

Comment: this code is in the form_load

_dataBasePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\db1.mdb";
// adjust path to find your xml
  haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
  mouth = new HaarCascade("Mouth.xml");
  lefteye = new HaarCascade("eye_left.xml");
  righteye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml");

and **cap=new capture();** is in the InitializeComponent();

Comment: post it as an edit to your question with proper tagging so its easily readable

Comment: The correct way is to start your timer in the form_load method so that to insure that the ListBox is initialized before starting any inserts on it.

Comment: but the timer is for the face detection only.. and in the designer code in the InitializeComponent() method there is  **this.playlistviewbar = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();**
after that also it is possible that listbox is not initialized before any inserts?